# How can I change permanently the Data Frame Style with Pandas in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styles, data-science

I'm using Jupyter Notebook and I'm not able to do what described in the title:
if I change the df style using df.style.apply(...) the df changes and be printed once as I want,
but if I print other times the same df if return to the standard style.
Is there a way to display the style setted multiple times without recalling df.style.apply everytime?

I used this solution find on this forum for the moment, but it only works once as I said over:

```
df.style.apply(lambda x: ['background: #f1ebdd' if x.name in [0,nrows,2]
                            else 'background : white' for i in x],
                            axis=1)
```

Comment: Can  `df.style.applymap` do the thing that you want? You define your change once as a functions and pass the function as argument to `applymap`.

Comment: I edited the post: as you can see I used a lambda function, but it doesn't work with applymap (it says "cannot assign to lambda")

Comment: ... axis=1,inplace=True)

Comment: it returns <lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'inplace'